# Excel Combo Box Drop Down (form control) non functional when Protected

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

EDIT:
Should've researched further. This solved it: https://excel.tips.net/T002691_Selecting_Combo_Boxes_in_Locked_Worksheets.html

Simply unlock the cell associated with combo box (right click, format cells, Protection, uncheck 'locked)

I replaced data validation with a combo box form control, which was working fine with the worksheet protected. Now with the combo box I get the message advising me of the sheet protection and it won't accept any changes (it works fine unprotected). I protect the sheet with the below code on WS open (I've seen some answers suggesting UserInterfaceOnly:= true would allow the combo box to function, but that is unfortunately not the case).

Any suggestions?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim Current As Worksheet
For Each Current In Worksheets

With Current
    .Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
End With

Next

Worksheets("Pivot").UnProtect

End Sub
```

Comment: If it's solved, then please include the solution as an answer (you can answer your own question) so others will know this question is answered. (when you do, include a brief explanation and not just the link)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Should've researched further. This solved it: https://excel.tips.net/T002691_Selecting_Combo_Boxes_in_Locked_Worksheets.html

Simply unlock the cell associated with combo box (right click, format cells, Protection, uncheck 'locked)

Answer (score 0):

I find method same you, but can not, but this code below, could help little.

```
Private sub Combobox1_changed()
  ActiveSheet.Unprotected  "0000"
End sub

Private sub Combobox1_gotFocus()
  Activesheet.Protect "0000"
End sub
```